# A sample of 210 sanitation workers for a city earns an average of $24,375 per year.

Tags: average

A sample of $210$ sanitation workers for a city earns an average of \$24,375 per year. A record also shows that the standard deviation of all city workers’ income is \$823. What is the average income of all sanitation workers in the city? Conduct an estimate at $0.05 ~ \alpha$ level.

Comment: What have you tried? [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will help you with your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Is there any more specificity to the question?  Otherwise the best estimate for the population mean is the sample mean.

Comment: have a look at [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)